# Использование Google Play Services в Qt

Tags: android, java, qt

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо взаимодействие с сервисами Google Play из-под Qt приложения. Ясное дело, код взаимодействия расположен в Java файле, а Qt вызывает методы этого файла.

Добавил библиотеку Play Services как указано [тут](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/android3rdpartylibs.html), всё собирается нормально, но при вызове методов из библиотеки получаем вот что:

```
W/dalvikvm(28101): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g; (169)
W/dalvikvm(28101): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g;' failed
I/dalvikvm(28101): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.api.g.a, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.gI
W/dalvikvm(28101): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3384: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g;.a (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g;
```

и ещё кучу замечательных ошибок...

Так вот вопрос: что пошло не так и как правильно добавить эту библиотеку в проект Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось избавится от ошибок добавлением библиотеки android support в проект.

Для этого просто скопировал её из `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4` в `PROJECT_DIR\ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR\libs`.